# Better dao design with Anorm

Tags: scala, anorm

I'm working on a code base has lots of singleton daos which getting a new connection from pool in each method with `DB.withConnection` then executes block.

Dao methods use Anorm parsers to parse result set. There are some cases each dao method run some other dao methods in anorm parsers to get nested related items for business model.

Let's assume you have data structure like this;

```
User -> Posts -> Comments for each posts
```

Dao work like this;

```
UserDao.getUser
   PostDao.getUserPosts
      CommentsDao.getPostComments
```

Because each dao method is calling DB.withConnection, multiple connections used for simple operations.

I want to use same connection. It can be done with `implicit connection` passing through each dao method.
But then I need to maintain connection allocation in upper layer. Right now daos accessed directly from rest actions, there is not any kind of service layer sitting between api and dao. I feel like it's not good to have connection around just in api layer.

So probably having services like UserService which calling daos and handling connection and transaction would be better.

Then another requirement is make me uncomfortable. Most of the dao methods also need to be called by individually.

For example we have api requesting comments only by;

```
CommentsDao.getPostComments
```

This means also I need to implement Services for all daos basically, overriding each dao methods with DB.withConnection wrapper, seems like a overhead. (~30 daos, ~10 methods)

Another limitation is that actually inner dao calls is done in anorm parsers, I think this one is misuse of the library;

When we change the each dao method definition to pass `implicit connection` around, parsers would fail to compile.

Because anorm parsers is `ResultSetParser[T]` , there is no way to pass connection inside it as default. Example parser is like;

```
val apiProviderParser = get[Int]("id") ~
get[String]("product_name") ~
get[String]("description") ~
get[String]("icon_url") map {

  case id ~ productName ~ desc ~ iconUrl => {

    //Inner dao call
    //Connection needed now 
    val params = getApiProviderParams(id)//(implicit connection)
    new ApiProviderTemplate(id,productName,desc,iconUrl,params)
  }
}
```

Maybe custom ResultSetParser[T] with connection in the scope can work, I'm not sure it's correct way of solving this problem.

I checked cake pattern, dao design issues but couldn't decide how to proceed and what's the pragmatic, good solution for this problem.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Parser should not do anything else than parsing the row (as depending on connection), that's where the misuse is.

Comment: Yeap thats what I thought, do you know whats the best practice for sub queries instead of join in anorm?

Comment: You can compose parsers, and apply it on SQL queries combining data from several tables/views.

Comment: I should do it without any change on sql queries because there are some cases 4 queries running with lots of join and result is one parent object. I think I move dao calls from parser to dao method itself and then merge with result object.

Comment: Why did you remove the tags from question? It's also a design problem,  rather than pure scala so I believe these tags can bring some bright people.